# Update relative time with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'd like to create an object with the key set to the time a button was clicked. I'd then like to check every second the current time versus the time created and console.log() the relative time. The problem being it never changes from 'A few seconds ago'. What am I missing?

Codepen Live Example: http://codepen.io/colealanroberts/pen/VLvpzR/?editors=001

Here's what I have thus far:

```
(function() {
  // HTML Elements
  var $btn = document.getElementById('save');
  var $relTime = document.getElementById('relative-time');  

  var tObj = {};
  var now = moment();
  var t = now.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

  function saveObj() {
      tObj = {
        timeClicked: t
  }
  // Log initial time
  console.log(tObj.timeClicked);

  setInterval(function() {
      var rel = moment([tObj.timeClicked]).fromNow(true);
      console.log(rel);
  }, 1000);
 }

  $btn.addEventListener('click', saveObj);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't save the moment but a string.

If you want to keep using that string, you must parse it:

```
var rel = moment(tObj.timeClicked,["dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"]).fromNow(true);
```

Of course it would be simpler to store the moment itself : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdOjqr